# `read` output to variable does not echo to console window

Tags: bash, shell

I have this script:

```
function input_message {
    echo -e "$1: "
    while read -r response; do
        case $response in
            "")
                return 1
                ;;
            *)
                echo $response
                ;;
            esac
        break
    done
}
```

And I am trying to do the following in another script:

```
INPUTVAR="$(input_message 'Input a value')"
```

However, what happens on the console window when this is run is as follows:

```
nick@laptop:~$ INPUTVAR="$(input_message 'Input a value')"
This is my input
Input a value: This is my input
```

Of course, I'd expect the function to do this:

```
nick@laptop:~$ INPUTVAR="$(input_message 'Input a value')"
Input a value: This is my input
This is my input
```

What's the correct way to achieve this? I have tried various types of command expansion techniques and can't seem to get it right :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a missing `{` in the function declaration.

The `echo` in the function does write `reponse` variable's value to standard output.

`INPUTVAR=$(...)` captures the standard output of the command executed in between `(...)` and assigned these outputs to `INPUTVAR`. That is why nothing is visible in the console.

When I test the function, I do not get the same result as you.

`read` has a `-p` option to display a prompt on standard error, which is going to be displayed in the console, when standard error is not redirected to something else.

Give a try to this, to both print to the console and assign a value to `INPUTVAR`:

```
$ cat fnlib.sh 

function input_message() {
    while read -r -p "${1}: " response; do
        case $response in
            "")
                return 1
                ;;
            *)
                printf "%s" "${response}"
                printf "%s\n" "${response}" >&2
                ;;
            esac
        break
    done
}

$ . fnlib.sh

$ INPUTVAR="$(input_message 'Input a value')"
Input a value: This is my input
This is my input
```

A second test with no value provided:

```
$ INPUTVAR="$(input_message 'Input a value')"
Input a value:
```

If user enters nothing and press the `[ENTER]` key, the function prints nothing to standard input, so `INPUTVAR` variable is assigned the *empty* string.

Comment: What if I want the `read -p "String"` to have colours defined etc.? Many thanks!

Comment: Answer to my own comment: `while read -r -p "${1}: " response;` to `printf "\e[0;34m%s\e[0m" "$MESSAGE: " >&2; while read -r -p "" response` - quick edit, in fact the blank `-p ""` option can be removed from that command, see the question edit

Answer (score 0):

Using `echo` to print the prompt makes the prompt a part of the result of the command substitution.  If you use `read -p` instead (which however is a bashism), or write the prompt to standard error, you get the result you expect.

```
value=$(printf "Read a value: " >&2; read -r input; echo "$input")
```

or

```
value=$(read -p "Read a value: " -r input; echo "$input")
```

Notice how `$input` will be unset, because the command substitution runs in a subshell.  The trick is to not print to standard output anything you don't want to end up in `$value`.

Of course, this is much, much easier with

```
read -p "Read a value:" value
```